# What is the lava thing for in the industrial centrifuge

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-industrialcraft

In the gui for the industrial centrifuge there is a lava area.

[image]

what is it used for? Can I speed up the machine this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is used to feed lava from a container object like a bucket.](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Industrial_Centrifuge)

By default you get:

16 Still Lava → 1 Tin Ingot + 4 Electrum Nugget + 2 Copper Ingot + 1 Tiny Pile of Tungsten Dust

This might be different depending on the pack.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the lava box is the place that the lava is stored from input via pipes.

Comment: Okey. But what does it do?